# Classify list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two list of dict like below in Python

```
L1 = [ {"v1":200,"v2":1},{"v1":300,"v2":2},{"v1":400,"v2":3},{"v1":500,"v2":4} ] 
L2 = [{"v1":200,"v2":1},{"v1":300,"v2":10}]
```

I want to classify them into 3 different list

```
Rule 1: If L1.V1 == L2.V1 AND L1.V2 == L2.V2 then Identical 
Rule 2: If L1.V1 not in L2.V1 then New
Rule 3:  If L1.V1 == L2.V1 AND L1.V2 != L2.V2 then Updated
```

Below is my code

```
           for l1 in L1:
                for l2 in L2:
                    if l1['V1'] == l2['V1']:
                        if l1['V2']  == l2['V2'] :
                            Identicall1.append(l1)
                        elif (l1['V2']  != l2['V2']):
                            updatedl1.append(l1)
                    else:
                        new_l1.append(l1)
```

It is not working as expected. And i found that it is not checking all the values in the L2.

**Update:**

Say for example:

```
1) Consider L1[0] and L2[0] both are same by Rule 1. So i want to push L1[0] into identical list 

2) consider L1[1] and L2[0] since the L1[1].V1 != L2[1].V1 skip and move to next in L2
   Compare L2[1] with L1[1] in this case L1[1].V2 != L2[1].V2 so by Rule 2 push this L1[1] into Update list 


3) L1[2].v1 and L1[3].v1 are not in L2 so push to new list
```

Can any one help me. Thanks,

**Update**

**Input**

```
L1 = [ {"v1":200,"v2":1},{"v1":300,"v2":2},{"v1":400,"v2":3},{"v1":500,"v2":4} ] 
    L2 = [{"v1":200,"v2":1},{"v1":300,"v2":10}]
```

**O/p**

```
new_l1= [{"v1":400,"v2":3},{"v1":500,"v2":4} ]
Update =[{"v1":300,"v2":2}]
Identical =[{"v1":200,"v2":1}]
```

Comment: What do you expect the result will be?

Comment: `L1.V1 == L2.V1 AND L1.V2 == L2.V2` Here  what is V1? Is it the first dict within L1, or is it the key v1 within that?

Comment: @Backtrack You should really post an **actual** example of input and output. Something like `l1 = [1,2,3]` , `l2 = [3, 4, 5]`, `identical = [3]`, `rest=[1, 2, 4, 5]`

Comment: HI @ReutSharabani i have added the i/p and o/p please help me

Comment: @Backtrack added an answer using list comprehensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

To create the `identical` list:

```
identical = [d for d in L1 if d in L2]
```

To create the `update` list:

```
L2v1s = set([d['v1'] for d in L2])
update = [d for d in L1 if d['v1'] in L2v1s and not d in identical]
```

To create the `new` list:

```
new = [d for d in L1 if not d in identical + update]
```

If performance is a problem you can use sets to make this **a lot** faster.

It would require using a data type other than `dict` as `dict` is not hashable.

Comment: It is really nice. But for finding Identical when i try the above i am getting error  .. for l1 in L1:
    if any(d['v1'] ==l1['v1'] and d['v2'] ==l1['v2'] for d in L2):
        identical.append(l1)  I am using like below for finding identical

Comment: I am getting identical = [ d in L1 if d in L2 ]   --> invalid syntax for this

Comment: @Backtrack fixed. If you don't know list comprehensions I've added a link.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sure i will have a look on the list comprehensions

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking into comparing two dicts from each list to check if they are identical or not. In that case, you can do:

```
L1 = [ {"v1":200,"v2":1},{"v1":300,"v2":2},{"v1":400,"v2":3},{"v1":500,"v2":4} ] 
L2 = [{"v1":200,"v2":1},{"v1":300,"v2":10}]

matching_dict = lambda d1, d2: all(key in d2 and d1[key] == d2[key] for key in d1)

if matching_dict(L1[0], L2[0]):
    if matching_dict(L1[1], L2[1])
        print "Identical"
    else:
        print "Updated"
else:
    print "New"
```

Note that we are currently checking for each dict by its index location in the list, a better approach in case of more than 2 such dict checks would be to use zip:

```
>>> zip(L1, L2)
[({'v1': 200, 'v2': 1}, {'v1': 200, 'v2': 1}),
 ({'v1': 300, 'v2': 2}, {'v1': 300, 'v2': 10})]
```